# InfluxDb top X offenders

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb

I have an InfluxDb time series database which I am storing a metric called `api_calls`.  This metric has two pertinent measurements, `call_invoked` and `call_failed`.  Each measurement also has a tag with a vendor id associated with it.

Every minute, I have a service that collates the number of times I invoked `call_invoked` (fired when I start the API call) and `call_failed` (fired when I get an error message from the API call) and stores them into an InfluxDb.  So basically, every minute I get a record (per tag, as I understand it) in the InfluxDb "table" (for lack of a better term) that has these two values associated with it.

I have been scratching my head trying to figure out how to show the top ten vendor id's with the largest percentage of API failures.

How can I do this?  I have a strong SQL background but everything I've tried has either not worked at all or definitely not worked correctly.

Comment: Have you tried building a CQ using `TOP()`? Something like `CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY top_10_offenders ON your_db_name BEGIN SELECT TOP("call_fail_sum", "vendor_id", "call_failed", 10) [,other tag keys] INTO dest_meas_name FROM meas_name GROUP BY time(1m) END` (refs: docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/functions/#‌​top docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/…)

Comment: ...I haven't.  I'll try it.

Comment: I'm curious. If you have the time, please share results, when you have them.

Comment: It didn't seem to work.  The CQ sent me some very strange data that didn't seem to map to anything.  It could just be my ignorance on InfluxDb syntax, but I think it's not supported.

Comment: Can you post a few sample "insert" lines to get a feel for what your schema looks like?

Comment: Also: what version of InfluxDB are you running?

Comment: I'm not explicitly inserting the data, it's done through an API call in my code, so I don't know what the inserts actually look like.  From my understanding of what the API does, it collects instances of calls with the measurements, values, and tags, and every minute collates them together and ships them off to the InfluxDb instance.

Comment: Commands like `SHOW TAG KEYS` and `SHOW FIELD KEYS` can help map the schema.

Comment: `SHOW MEASUREMENTS` too.

Answer (score 3):

I've made some guesses about your schema, and built up a solution using the CLI. I'm using InfluxDB v1.0.2 here.

*Note that `TOP()` only became a working function around January 2016*.

If your version of InfluxDB is older than this, the following won't work.

First, some sample data:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo
USE foo
PRECISION rfc3339

INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=1 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=3i 1483228860000000000
INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=2 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=8i 1483228860000000000
INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=3 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=5i 1483228860000000000
INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=4 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=9i 1483228860000000000
INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=5 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=10i 1483228860000000000
INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=6 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=1i 1483228860000000000
INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=7 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=6i 1483228860000000000
INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=8 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=9i 1483228860000000000
INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=9 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=6i 1483228860000000000
INSERT api_calls,vendor_id=10 call_invoked=3i,call_failed=5i 1483228860000000000
```

Then run the following query. Note that the `WHERE time > x AND time < y` clause could be replaced with something like `WHERE time > now() - 1h`.

```
SELECT TOP(call_failed,3), vendor_id FROM api_calls WHERE time > '2017-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND time < '2017-01-01T00:05:00Z' GROUP BY time(1m)
```

Which gives a result of:

```
name: api_calls
---------------
time                    top     vendor_id
2017-01-01T00:00:00Z
2017-01-01T00:01:00Z    10      5
2017-01-01T00:01:00Z    9       4
2017-01-01T00:01:00Z    9       8
2017-01-01T00:02:00Z
2017-01-01T00:03:00Z
2017-01-01T00:04:00Z
```

Note that every minute that has no data returns one row, but where there is data, there are 3 rows returned.

If we tell the CLI we want to peek at the JSON, we can type `format json`, and when we repeat that same query we get this:

```
{"results":[{"series":[{"name":"api_calls","columns":["time","top","vendor_id"],"values":[["2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",null,null],["2017-01-01T00:01:00Z",10,"5"],["2017-01-01T00:01:00Z",9,"4"],["2017-01-01T00:01:00Z",9,"8"],["2017-01-01T00:02:00Z",null,null],["2017-01-01T00:03:00Z",null,null],["2017-01-01T00:04:00Z",null,null]]}]}]}
```

Does that help?

### Edit - Re-worked for percentage.

Apologies - I noticed you were looking for percentage, not Top X count.

In InfluxDB, that's two problems: the first is how to generate the percentages.

A note about nesting operators in functions: InfluxDB does not yet generally guarantee that nesting functions or operators within function arguments will work. Some do, many don't. Of importance here: `TOP()` only allows *field keys or tags* as arguments, and not operations on tags (e.g. call_failed / total_calls). You'll need to perform an extra query to generate the percentages, and you'll have to store them. You can either calculate them on the "raw", minute-by-minute values:

```
SELECT (call_failed / (call_failed + call_invoked)) AS pct_fail INTO api_calls FROM api_calls GROUP BY vendor_id
```

(`GROUP BY time` is implicit: re-run that query from the CLI without the `INTO` clause to see how).

Or you can summarize each e.g. hour:

```
SELECT (sum(call_failed) / (sum(call_failed) + sum(call_invoked))) AS pct_fail INTO api_calls_hourly FROM api_calls GROUP BY time(1h), vendor_id
```

That can be done as a one-off for existing data. For any newly arriving data, a continuous query can be used:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY fail_pct_calc ON foo BEGIN SELECT (sum(call_failed) / (sum(call_failed) + sum(call_invoked))) AS pct_fail INTO api_calls_summary FROM api_calls GROUP BY time(1h), vendor_id END
```

(continuous queries require a `GROUP BY time()` clause).

There's no technical requirement to push Continuous Query results into a new measurement - you could `SELECT` the calculation results back `INTO api_calls`, for example. But putting the raw data and the summary results in the same measurement leads to query results that have a *lot* of nulls. It's often tidier in InfluxDB to push the results to a new measurement.

From there, use `TOP()` as before:

### Edited - fixed 'FROM' measurement

```
SELECT TOP(pct_fail,3), vendor_id FROM api_calls_summary WHERE time > '2017-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND time < '2017-01-01T00:05:00Z' GROUP BY time(1m)
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot to digest!  I'll dig into this and see if I can make it work, thanks!

Comment: I found my own SQL background helped less than I'd hoped with InfluxDB. When I was learning German, there are a lot of words that look similar to English but have completely different meanings. These are called "false friends" by German teachers. Influx query language is a bit like that with regards to SQL. So if some of it seems jarring or odd compared to what you're used to in a relational database, don't worry - it's not just you. :) It's also not only InfluxDB - every time series database I've worked with over the past 20 years has been like this. They're strange beasts.